# Ignore column if not extist in table Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an abtract class like below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;

//getters and setters 
}
```

and two entity extend BaseEntity

Fist class

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "table1")
public class TValideB  extends BaseEntity {

 @Column(name = "phone")
 String phone;
```

}

Second class

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "table2")
public class TValide extends BaseEntity {

    @Colmun(name = "mail")
    String mail;

}
```

When i try to save TValide  i get error like this `non valid column "name"`;
In my table2 non column  exsit for name.

My question is how can i ignore this column and save my entity? 
Exist an other approaches without delete column name from abstract 
 class?

Comment: The point of making an abstract Base Entity is so that every other Entity can extend it, so only provide absolutely necessary fields in abstract classes. If you need name in one entity and not in others it is generally not suitable to keep it in BaseEntity.

Comment: @ROHAN. yes but i search if exisit other approaches and thanks

Comment: Yes it's okay. I was suggesting. I have posted an answer, let me know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add `@Column` in name with insertable=false, updatable=false  edit my abstract class like below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    String name;

//getters and setters 
}
```

This approach avoid me to create a lot of abstract class or rewrite override attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use base classes, you can create two.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class BaseEntityWithId {

    @Id
    Long id;

//getters and setters 
}

@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class BaseEntityWithName extends BaseEntityWithId {

  String name;    

//getters and setters 
}
```

Then you simply have to pick the right one depending on the column layout of the table.

Comment: I followed this approach in first but i have a lot of table and entity so if i fllow your approach i need to create a lot of abstract class to meet need

Comment: @A.khalifa eventually you have to stop ignoring signals that the approach you are taking is the wrong one. In my experience, having flat entities which define all the properties that are in them and using Lombok to minimise boilerplate code is the only way to go. You can even generate entity code, most IDEs have a plugin or a built-in feature to do so. If you make that little up-front effort, your future self will thank you when a change on the database is suddenly demanded and it only takes one small change in one entity to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. 
In your class that extends `BaseEntity`, do this for the column that you don't want.

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public class TValide extends BaseEntity {

    @Colmun(name = "mail")
    String mail;

}
```

Comment: imagine if i hava a lot of attibute in abstract class so in each entity i need to use AttributeOverride is painful :(

Comment: Yes but that seems to be the only solution and it isn't as painful because you only have to write it once in your class. And as I said, if your BaseEntity is actually an abstract class and only has absolutely necessary fields you probably won't need to do this a lot of times

Comment: em but i need to rewrite Column already exist in BaseEntity :(

Comment: Why would you need to rewrite column that already exists in BaseEntity?

Comment: to define AttributeOverride in my entity

Comment: like i need to develop an annotation to make coulmn necessary or not

Comment: Yes I can understand but that is the least you can do to achieve what you want to achieve as far as I know :) You will only need it when you want to make column NOT necessary btw

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you use abstraction. Create a new abstract class that extends BaseEntity contains fields that are rarely used.

Example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class BaseEntity {

   @Id
   Long id;

   //getters and setters 
}


@MappedSuperclass
public  abstract class BaseNameEntity extends BaseEntity {

   String name;

   //getters and setters 
}


@Entity
@Table(name= "table1")
public class TValideB  extends BaseNameEntity {

  @Column(name = "phone")
  String phone;

  //getters and setters 
}



@Entity
@Table(name= "table2")
public class TValide extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "mail")
  String mail;

  //getters and setters 
}
```

By doing this you can configure all your structure.